# Reducing NTP offset with local server and Windows 10

Tags: windows, ntp

I'm trying to synchronize my Windows 10 (22H2) workstation with our local NTP server.
I already synced another Linux device and I got <1ms offset:

```
nvidia@nvidia-orin-rt:~$ ntpdate -q 10.1.2.3 server 10.1.2.3,
stratum 3, offset -0.000023, delay 0.02728 27 Jul 07:54:47
ntpdate[3894]: adjust time server 10.1.2.3 offset -0.000023 sec
```

on Windows side I set the NTP IP into the 'Internet NTP url' (before it was time.windows.com) and I checked the new offset:

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:10.1.2.3 /packetinfo
Tracking 10.1.2.3 [10.1.2.3:123].
The current time is 27/07/2023 11:48:59 AM
11:48:59:, d:+00.0010997s o:-00.4798921s  [                          *|                           ]
[NTP Packet]
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Version Number: 3
Mode: 4 (Server)
Stratum: 3 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
Poll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
Precision: -23 (119.209ns per tick)
Root Delay: 0x0000.01AC (+00.0065308s)
Root Dispersion: 0x0000.1788 (0.0919189s)
ReferenceId: 0x0AA10316 (source IP:  10.1.5.6)
Reference Timestamp: 0xE86C9E79384F6C4E (154339 07:42:49.2199619s - 27/07/2023 11:42:49 AM)
Originate Timestamp: 0xE86C9FEB06FD3621 (154339 07:48:59.0273012s - 27/07/2023 11:48:59 AM)
Receive Timestamp: 0xE86C9FEA8C4708D3 (154339 07:48:58.5479589s - 27/07/2023 11:48:58 AM)
Transmit Timestamp: 0xE86C9FEA8C4755FF (154339 07:48:58.5479635s - 27/07/2023 11:48:58 AM)
[non-NTP Packet]
Destination Timestamp: Roundtrip Delay: 1099700 (+00.0010997s)
Local Clock Offset: -479892100 (-00.4798921s)
```

This is the configuration:

```
C:\Windows\system32> w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)
FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 360000 (Local)

[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 32768 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: 10.1.2.3,0x9 (Local) 

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

To sync I did:

```
net stop w32tm
net start w32tm
w32tm /resync /force
```

But it doesn't adjust the 479ms it mentioned.